# Upload local Vagrant package.box to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vagrant

So, I've been working locally in a vagrant ubuntu box for the past month: I've spent a lot of time working on customizing it and installing exactly all the software I want on it.  I started all of this through the normal vagrant [tutorial](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/) (aka, nothing special).  I [packaged](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/boxes.html) my local vagrant box into a `package.box` file.  *Now*, I want to move my development environment (e.g. `package.box` file) to an Amazon EC2 instance on AWS.  I know I'm not supposed to ask for software recommendations, but my question is basically: is this possible to do and, if it is, could you point me to some examples of people doing it?  I've read that [packer](https://www.packer.io/) might be an option, but it looks to me (a very inexperienced perspective) that maybe I should have *started* with that instead of trying to use it now.  Any help would be appreciated - I don't want to spend a couple weeks setting up a new environment when I have one locally set up.

**Edit**:

Progress! I followed @error2007s link and followed the tutorial.  I'm at the point where I've uploaded the VMDK image to s3 and provisioned an instance using it (all done automatically with the `ec2-import-instance` command on the CLI).  However, I don't see a Public IP to access the new instance after I start it up.
I *think* this is related to `cloud-init` somehow, but I'm not sure what that is really.  I tried it with both the `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` file that came with the box as well as the one listed [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/create-an-ami-from-your-own-vm-image) and neither of the two boxes I uploaded gave me a Public IP to access.

**Edit 2**:

Here are some things I see in the Console (They all seem right to me, but a more experienced eye might see something wrong):

subnet info:

`Auto-assign Public IP: yes`

Network ACL:
[image]

VPC info:

`DNS resolution: yes`

`DNS hostnames: yes`

`ClassicLink DNS Support: no`

`VPC CIDR: 172.31.0.0/16`

DHCP Option Set:

`Options: domain-name = ec2.internal domain-name-servers = AmazonProvidedDNS`

From my perspective, those all look right, or am I missing something?
I assigned an Elastic IP per [these instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/GettingStartedGuide/getting-started-assign-eip.html), but when I `ssh ec2-user@<elastic-ip>`, it says `ssh: connect to host <elastic-ip> port 22: Connection refused`.  The security group assigned to the instance is set to allow all protocols on all ports.  Also, this is the first time I encounter a Elastic IP and I'm unsure what exactly it is doing.

Comment: When you are moving your local to AWS do you want to remain dependent on Vagrant for accessing the EC2 instance?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.  What I _think_ I want is to register an AMI with amazon and from that point, I'll be able to easily work with it using vagrant (as @rodrigo-m pointed out below).  I'm currently following the instructions in your answer and we'll see if it works

Comment: One good pattern is to continue to use Vagrant both in development and when pushing an instance to EC2.  Then you do not have to prebake an AMI, and loose vagrant configuration options. Once configured with the AWS provider, you can save the AMI image of course.

Comment: You launching in a VPC?  Check your subnet settings re the public IP assignment.  Make sure the subnet itself is public.  Assign an elastic IP if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon enables you to transfer your Vm to AWS as a EC2 instance. Check this tutorial this is more simple.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/UsingVirtualMachinesinAmazonEC2.html

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the Vagrant AWS provider found here:

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws

> This is a Vagrant 1.2+ plugin that adds an AWS provider to Vagrant,
>   allowing Vagrant to control and provision machines in EC2 and VPC.

This will allow you to provision your AWS instances using Vagrant, allowing you to migrate the same local development environment to an AWS EC2 instance.

There is a good tutorial here:

https://nurmrony.wordpress.com/2015/03/15/vagrant-deploy-and-provisioning-an-amazon-ec2-instance/

Comment: Yea, I found that earlier.  From my understanding, that's for _starting_ out using vagrant + AWS.  I'll keep this in mind next time I start from scratch

Comment: I don' think it matters.  Add the 6-10 fields to your existing vagrant file, then `vagrant up --provider=aws` Then you have a working instance. Make an AMI from there if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have found these articles but I have not yet tested them myself.  Im still in the middle of organizing my personal notes and identifying my technology stack.  I intend to have a Homestead vagrant box be replicated as an EC2 instance, so I wont have to configure the instance(s) manually.

https://nurmrony.wordpress.com/2015/03/15/vagrant-deploy-and-provisioning-an-amazon-ec2-instance/

https://www.tothenew.com/blog/using-vagrant-to-deploy-aws-ec2-instances/

https://foxutech.com/how-to-deploy-on-amazon-ec2-with-vagrant/

https://blog.scottlowe.org/2016/09/15/using-vagrant-with-aws/

https://devops.com/devops-primer-using-vagrant-with-aws/

I find their approaches similar.  The only thing that I am worried at is the "vagrant add box" part.

I asked myselft, what if I had to do this setup again for familiarization purposes, what will happen since I already added a vagrant box (the dummy one, as instructed in the tutorials) previously.