# ec2-import-instance makes an instance with no Public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vagrant

This is related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332679/upload-local-vagrant-package-box-to-aws).  Basically, to summarize: I

1) Set up a vagrant ubuntu 14.04 box locally

2) Packaged the vagrant instance into a `package.box` following [these instructions](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/boxes.html)

3) Converted the `package.box` into a `.vmdk` file using [this function](https://github.com/dliappis/amiimporter/blob/master/amiimporter.py#L48)

4) Ran the following CLI command:

```
 ec2-import-instance tmpdir/box-disk1.vmdk -f VMDK -t t2.micro -a x86_64 -b <S3 Bucket> -o $AWS_ACCESS_KEY -w $AWS_SECRET_KEY -p Linux
```

Since I suspected the problem was with something called `cloud-init` I read about (but have never used/don't really know what it does), I tried the above twice: once with the original `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` file and again with the `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` file I found [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/create-an-ami-from-your-own-vm-image).

Basically, what I'm eventually seeing in the AWS Console is a running instance that does not have a Public IP address.  I attached an Elastic IP to the instance, but I can't ssh into that IP address for some reason - it says `port 22: Connection refused`

I'm at a loss because these instances are launching in the Default VPC which has a security group attached to it that allows all ports and all protocols from any IP.

By the way: I'm pretty new to all of AWS and don't really know my way fully around the console, so any direct guidance would be much appreciated.

Original `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` file:

```
# The top level settings are used as module
# and system configuration.

# A set of users which may be applied and/or used by various modules
# when a 'default' entry is found it will reference the 'default_user'
# from the distro configuration specified below
users:
   - default

# If this is set, 'root' will not be able to ssh in and they
# will get a message to login instead as the above $user (ubuntu)
disable_root: true

# This will cause the set+update hostname module to not operate (if true)
preserve_hostname: false

# Example datasource config
# datasource:
#    Ec2:
#      metadata_urls: [ 'blah.com' ]
#      timeout: 5 # (defaults to 50 seconds)
#      max_wait: 10 # (defaults to 120 seconds)

# The modules that run in the 'init' stage
cloud_init_modules:
 - migrator
 - seed_random
 - bootcmd
 - write-files
 - growpart
 - resizefs
 - set_hostname
 - update_hostname
 - update_etc_hosts
 - ca-certs
 - rsyslog
 - users-groups
 - ssh

# The modules that run in the 'config' stage
cloud_config_modules:
# Emit the cloud config ready event
# this can be used by upstart jobs for 'start on cloud-config'.
 - emit_upstart
 - disk_setup
 - mounts
 - ssh-import-id
 - locale
 - set-passwords
 - grub-dpkg
 - apt-pipelining
 - apt-configure
 - package-update-upgrade-install
 - landscape
 - timezone
 - puppet
 - chef
 - salt-minion
 - mcollective
 - disable-ec2-metadata
 - runcmd
 - byobu

# The modules that run in the 'final' stage
cloud_final_modules:
 - rightscale_userdata
 - scripts-vendor
 - scripts-per-once
 - scripts-per-boot
 - scripts-per-instance
 - scripts-user
 - ssh-authkey-fingerprints
 - keys-to-console
 - phone-home
 - final-message
 - power-state-change

# System and/or distro specific settings
# (not accessible to handlers/transforms)
system_info:
   # This will affect which distro class gets used
   distro: ubuntu
   # Default user name + that default users groups (if added/used)
   default_user:
     name: ubuntu
     lock_passwd: True
     gecos: Ubuntu
     groups: [adm, audio, cdrom, dialout, dip, floppy, netdev, plugdev, sudo, video]
     sudo: ["ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"]
     shell: /bin/bash
   # Other config here will be given to the distro class and/or path classes
   paths:
      cloud_dir: /var/lib/cloud/
      templates_dir: /etc/cloud/templates/
      upstart_dir: /etc/init/
   package_mirrors:
     - arches: [i386, amd64]
       failsafe:
         primary: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
         security: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
       search:
         primary:
           - http://%(ec2_region)s.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
           - http://%(availability_zone)s.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
           - http://%(region)s.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
         security: []
     - arches: [armhf, armel, default]
       failsafe:
         primary: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
         security: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
   ssh_svcname: ssh
```

Second try `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` file:

```
users:
 - default
disable_root: 1
ssh_pwauth:   0
locale_configfile: /etc/sysconfig/i18n
mount_default_fields: [~, ~, 'auto', 'defaults,nofail', '0', '2']
resize_rootfs_tmp: /dev
ssh_deletekeys:   0
ssh_genkeytypes:  ~
syslog_fix_perms: ~
cloud_init_modules:
 - bootcmd
 - write-files
 - resizefs
 - set_hostname
 - update_hostname
 - update_etc_hosts
 - rsyslog
 - users-groups
 - ssh
cloud_config_modules:
 - mounts
 - locale
 - set-passwords
 - timezone
 - runcmd
cloud_final_modules:
 - scripts-per-once
 - scripts-per-boot
 - scripts-per-instance
 - scripts-user
 - ssh-authkey-fingerprints
 - keys-to-console
 - final-message
system_info:
  distro: rhel
  default_user:
    name: ec2-user
  paths:
    cloud_dir: /var/lib/cloud
    templates_dir: /etc/cloud/templates
  ssh_svcname: sshd
EOF
```

Comment: Can you check the subnet settings in which your instance was created. Do you see that IGW in this screenshot? https://www.dropbox.com/s/9sn6y9o5jl7hg6h/SCSH.png?dl=0

Comment: Yea, I see it (this is the only subnet I have): http://i.imgur.com/aQqtKQZh.jpg

Comment: What command and key did you use to ssh into the instance?

Comment: I tried `ssh ubuntu@<elastic ip>` as well a `ssh ec2-user@<elastic ip>` both without a key - I wasn't able to find instructions for how to set up a key before uploading the box to aws

Comment: You will have to use a Key for that, thats why you are not able to SSH. In the Instance description below "Security Groups" you will see "Key pair name" do you see any key there?

Comment: Ah, ok. No there is nothing listed for "Key Pair Name"

Comment: Do one thing take a AMI of your instance. And then launch that AMI using a Key Pair you will be asked to create a Key Pair when you are launching the AMI download that key change the permission of the key to Chmod 400 and then use the command ssh -i ubuntu@IPAddress

Comment: Wow - making an AMI took a while. But it worked!! Thank you so much!! Do you want to write an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Done also for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332679/upload-local-vagrant-package-box-to-aws if you followed them and it worked please mark my answer correct there too thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because when you transferred the instance to AWS from your local there was no any PEM key associated with that instance due to which you were not able to SSH.

After you took an Image of your instance and launched the instance again with a associated key you were able to SSH into the instance.